# How to convert gif-file to numpy array in Python3 without Pillow

Tags: arrays, image, python-3.x, numpy

There is no PIL on Python3. Pillow seems to be the right way but it is not in a standard library. Is there a way to convert gif (or another image format) to numpy array that is not require installation of additional python packages?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the libraries PILasOPENCV or gif2numpy from Pypi. Install them with

```
pip install gif2numpy
```

gif2numpy works like this:

```
import gif2numpy
import cv2
np_frames, extensions, image_specifications = gif2numpy.convert("yourimage.gif")
cv2.imshow("test", np_frames[0])
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SciPy installed (as, I assume, most people using NumPy do), **ndimage** allows you to read in images as NumPy arrays:

```
from scipy import ndimage
im_array = ndimage.imread("image_file.gif")
```

Comment: This fails with an error: `module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'imread'`

Comment: imread was deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and removed in 1.2.0. The doc states to use imageio.imread instead, which uses PIL.

Answer (score 0):

ndimage is good. if you don't wanna see deprecated warning, you can use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_array = plt.imread('image_file.gif')
```

Comment: This loads only the first frame

Comment: @DavidTaub yes, it is

Comment: I get the error of ==> ValueError: output array is read-only